# Definition of a text file

Tags: binary, text-files

I'm not really a professional programmer (I just do some number crunching), I'm just trying to learn more some things about computing.

I'm here to ask for -a reference- for a reading regarding the basic aspects of a 'file'. I'm having difficulty to understand the difference between text files and binary files. With my current understaning an image file is no more 'binary' than a text file. I'd like to understand what makes a file a text file. Is it a special sequence of bits?

Please, I just need a good reading reference (although some clarification would be welcome) and I'm not really trying to make a vague, generic, question.

Preferable, I'd like to be pointed to a technical reading containing definitions such as "a text file is a sequence of bits whose etc..."

Thanks,
Seneika.

BTW: what one finds on Wikipedia, for example, is not what I want.

Edit: horrible grammar mistake corrected...

Comment: While I can't give you a good explanation try opening a text file in a hex editor and then try opening a PNG in a hex editor. This wikipedia article can explain to you what all of the bits in the PNG file mean. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header.

Comment: Your question does not really make sense. A text file *is* a binary file, and an image file *is* a binary file, in the sense they are both just a sequence of bits. Please clarify what you mean when you say "Binary file"?

Comment: @RB Perhaps I didn't make myself very clear but isn't your comment the same as what I've said with "an image file is no more 'binary' than a text file." I'm trying to understand why the distinction appears so often.

Comment: The distinction appears often because text files are so useful to us humans that we pretend they are different. When people say "text file" they mean "a file I can open in a text editor and understand", whereas by binary file they mean "A file that cannot be read by us puny humans, because it cannot be opened in a text-editor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A text file is a computer file that stores a typed document as a
>   series of alphanumeric characters, usually without visual formatting
>   information. The content may be a personal note or list, a journal or
>   newspaper article, a book, or any other text that can be rendered
>   accurately in typewritten form. Text files are similar to word
>   processing files in that the content of both is primarily textual;
>   they differ in that text files usually do not record information such
>   as character style and size, pagination, or other details that would
>   specify the appearance of a finished document. Some computer operating
>   systems make a basic distinction between a text file, which is
>   intended to be translated directly into human-readable text, and a
>   binary file, which is interpreted directly by the computer.

Source :  [Binary File](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-binary-file.htm) & [Text File](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-text-file.htm)
More details on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file)

Comment: Hi, AppDeveloper, let me put it this way: suppose you give me a Hex editor to create a 'file'. What would it mean to create a 'text' file in it? (Saving it as 'text' doesn't count...)

Comment: files are nothing by a collection of bitstream (bytes), a file is just a sequence of bytes, so yes if u create a file in hex editor and save it as .txt extension it will end up as a text file!

Comment: we call a file with extension .txt (in windows) as Text File because they are flat files they contain data in human readable form, u can even open EXE (executable file) on a notepad, but that wont be in much of a human readable format!

Comment: @RB and AppDeveloper. So a text file is simply a sequence of bits representing characters in ASCII, for example? If I write a file in a hex editor putting in it only these kind of bytes it will end up being a text file? No other strings attached? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you in your quest to answer your question :-)

http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-binary-file.htm